# Issue with Designing an ER Diagram for a Question-Based Learning Program - Fixing many to many relationships

Tags: python, database, entity

I need to make an entity relationship diagram in the function of my program consists of the student in a session with many questions being linked to it. The questions would have randomly selected math questions. To see if they get it wrong or right,  the student will confirm that they are done and the correct answer will be shown. The  student will then be asked if they got it right, if they haven't then more questions of that same type will be shown. I want the teacher to be able to see what questions the student has gotten wrong and right. The questions should also have tags which indicate the type of math question and it should have the level of difficulty.

My initial problems were that there are many-to-many relationships. An ER diagram I made is shown without many-to-many relationships but I'm unsure on how the database would store the correct answer and know if the student has gotten it right or wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated. [image: image 1]